# NEST - Is there a way to add a raw filter string to a Filtered Query?

Tags: nest

I know I can use QueryRaw and FilterRaw but I want the ability to add a raw filter string to a filtered query.  Unfortunately, it looks like FilterDescriptor.Raw is internal.  Am I missing something?

The closest I've come is

```
var filter = ((ISearchRequest) new SearchDescriptor<object>().FilterRaw("<raw filter here>")).Filter;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to come up with a reason why we made it internal, can you please open a Github issue for this:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues

That way it wont drop off our radar.